# Unsure how to turn this jQuery code to React

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm trying to incorporate [this](https://codepen.io/albizan/pen/mMWdWZ) HTML/CSS/JS codepen template into my react website. I'm trying to turn this piece of jQuery code to react:

```
$('.navTrigger').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            console.log("Clicked menu");
            $("#mainListDiv").toggleClass("show_list");
            $("#mainListDiv").fadeIn();
        
        });
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Navbar1.css';

class Navbar extends Component {

    state = { navbarActive: false }

    navbarClick = () => {
        this.setState({ navbarActive: !this.state.navbarActive })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="#">Your Logo</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mainListDiv" className={this.state.navbarActive ? "show_list" : "main_list"}>
                            <ul className="navlinks">
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <span className="navTrigger" onClick={this.navbarClick}>
                            <i></i>
                            <i></i>
                            <i></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

I am using the exact same CSS as the one on the codepen. I am unsure why it is not working (when hamburger navbar icon is clicked, it doesn't turn into an X and doesn't display a dropdown of the navbar items) and would appreciate some assistance.

EDIT -------------------------

I don't know how to turn this piece of jQuery into React and am not sure how to start:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.nav').addClass('affix');
                console.log("OK");
            } else {
                $('.nav').removeClass('affix');
            }
        });
```

This is for the same codepen template as well, it basically adds a black background to the navbar when you start scrolling. How do I make it so that I can see if a user scrolls past a certain height, then trigger a function (the above jQuery)?

Comment: where is hamburger navbar icon on the codepen. I'm not able to find it

Comment: by hamburger navbar icon I mean when you resize the screen, the hamburger icon shows up at the top right. This icon can be found in the lines `.navTrigger` and `.navTrigger i`, these classes make the icon. The root to the icon is `.navTrigger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a state for `navTrigger` whic tell us whether it `active` or not as:

```
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
```

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-hooks-muh0hi?file=/src/App.js)

then you can make a `ref` for `main_list`

```
  const mainListDivRef = useRef(null);
```

> You can add animation as per your requirement

then on click of hamburger icon you can perform operation as:

```
function onClickNavTrigger() {
    setIsActive((a) => !a);
    const mainListDivEl = mainListDivRef.current;
    mainListDivEl.classList.toggle("show_list");
  }
```

Comment: with the code that you provided in the codesandbox link, how do I render that? I'm seperating all my components (ex. Navbar, homepage) and I've been using classes for that. With a function, how do I import it in my `App.js` and use it? Currently I'm doing `<Navbar/>` once I call it like this `import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';`.

Comment: Exactly like you use with `class` like `<Navbar />`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it helped me learn a lot about states and refs! I was also just wondering if you knew how to turn the jQuery for the code which I edited on to my first post into React as well, it deals with scrolling past a certain limit.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to the root directory of your react project and open terminal to install jQuery using the below-mentioned command.

**npm install jquery --save**

2- import jquery

**import $ from 'jquery'**

3- Now create a function and put your jquery code inside that function. For this tutorial purpose, I have created a lorem ipsum text and button and I will use jQuery CSS API to change the color of lorem ipsum text by clicking on that button, and  call that function inside the componentDidMount lifecycle method. ***like this:***

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {        
    jQuerycode = () => {
       // Jquery here $(...)...
      
        });
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        this.jQuerycode()
      }
  }
```

Comment: I did this but it's not working, I can see in the console that it's saying "Clicked menu", but it is not acting like it is on the codepen